# Using ASP.NET Web API as Hangfire Job Storage

Tags: asp.net, hangfire

I read through the documentation, and it seems like, any client and server that uses Hangfire, needs direct access to the db, wether its sql server, sql azure or redis.

As i don't have direct access to our job storage (db) i would like to access it via running a web app (probably asp net core web api would be a fitting candidate). Are there any job storage implementations known for that? Or am i simply missing something from the documentation?

I would rather avoid writing my own job storage implementation.

Comment: Hangfire would need a storage for any job metadata. There are different storage db that can be used as per hangfire doc https://www.hangfire.io/extensions.html

Answer (score 1):

Hangfire check to database for last transactions and according to this checks, it take action. So you need access to database.

Comment: Sure, i understand. Its nothing that can't be implemented into a web api though, so i thought maybe someone else already solved that problem